# Setting the endscale in filled.contour function

Tags: r

I have to plot a physical variable over a world map at differents moments. So i have to make many plot as how many moments i have to plot. The problem is that my routine set the end of the scale by default, and this make the reading of the plot difficult. I would like to fix the end of the scale, in order to have one scale for all the plots. This is piece of an old code i would reuse

```
  require(reshape)
  require(mapdata)
  require(mapproj)
  df <- read.table('/media/Lacie2/dati/hy.dat',head=F)
  names(df) <- c("value", "x", "y")#, "t")
  dfc <- cast(df[ ,-4], x ~ y)
  mm<-as.matrix(dfc,ncol=480,nrow=241)
  filled.contour(x=seq(0,360,length.out=480),y=seq(-90,90,length.out=241),mm,
  color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "blue","violet", "black")),
  xlab = "Longitude (°)", ylab = "Latitude (°)",
  plot.axes = {axis(1); axis(2);            
  map('world2Hires',
  xlim = c(0, 360), 
  ylim = c(-90, 90), 
  add = T, col = "black")}
 )
```

I don't understand how to fix the endscale of the ladder. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot colors only up to a maximum, then just 'trim' the `value` that you pass to the plot routine with:

```
df$trimval <- pmin(df$value, 2)  
 # the range in the example below is roughly -4.5 to 4.5
```

... and plot using that value as the z-argument to `contour.plot`. Indented code and random "value" argument below:

```
require(reshape)
  require(mapdata)
  require(mapproj)
  df <- data.frame(value=rnorm( 480*241), x=seq(0,360,length.out=480),y=seq(-90,90,length.out=241) )
df$trimval <- pmin(df$value, 2)

  dfc <- cast(df[-1], x ~ y)
  mm<-as.matrix(dfc,ncol=480,nrow=241)
  filled.contour(x=seq(0,360,length.out=480),y=seq(-90,90,length.out=241),mm,
         color.palette = colorRampPalette(c("lightblue", "blue","violet", "black")),
         xlab = "Longitude (°)", ylab = "Latitude (°)",
         plot.axes = {axis(1); axis(2);            
                      map('world2Hires',
                      xlim = c(0, 360), 
                      ylim = c(-90, 90), 
                      add = T, col = "black")}
                )
```

The color range is therefore maxxed out at 2 and all of the values above 2 are plotted with the color given to 2. (I might mention that I tried using zlim and the results were not as I imagined you would want.)